# Parse HTML data in Java including &lt and &gt tags?

Tags: java, html-parsing, htmleditorkit

I want to parse HTML text in Java.

I have tried to parse HTML data using **javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit**. It helped me to  get data from HTML. But I have a HTML data like -

```
&lt;span class="TitleServiceChange" &gt;Service Change&lt;/span&gt;
                    &lt;span class="DateStyle"&gt;
                    &amp;nbsp;Posted:&amp;nbsp;12/16/2012&amp;nbsp; 8:00PM
                    &lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
                  &lt;P&gt;
```

with surrounding **'&lt'** and **'&gt'**  instead of **'<'** and **'>'**

While parsing the above text I am getting the error -

```
Parsing error: start.missing body ? ? at
```

Please suggest me to resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The HTML data you have shown above is not HTML as it has no tags. You should use String.replace if you wish to convert the HTML entities into a valid XML structure.

Comment: @TomLeese, If I paste this data in browser it shows correctly, also I tried in http://view.xmlgrid.net/ , then it shows in correct format

Comment: @Deepu : Strictly speaking, the string you show above is just that - a string (thus should display as *text*, not be processed as markup).

Comment: Browsers nowadays have a lot of error-correction built-in so if it is rendering, your browser might actually be "fixing" the code you entered by converting the &lt; and &gt; symbols before processing it as markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unescaping the full set of escaped characters included at a string, you could make use of the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html) utility library.

Specifically, using the [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class, where you can find the `unescapeHtml4` method, among others.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get the `String` representation of the data, replacing it with the correct tags could resolve your problem:

```
String htmlData = ...

htmlData = htmlData.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
htmlData = htmlData.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
```

Comment: What about the `&amp;` or the `&nbsp;` symbols?

Comment: @TomasNarros you can apply replaceAll for these also. what do you suspect from?

Comment: I looks like a full escaped HTML fragment. There are other symbols that could be included. Your solution could be useful if the content is restricted just to a predefined set of symbols. Don't you agree?

Comment: Ya @TomasNarros is pointing the right issue, there may be many number of tags included like &amp, br etc, How should I work on it.

Comment: @Deepu you can use a hashmap in that case where you get replacement for various html tags from a hashmap that you should have previously populated in your code.

Comment: @ivanovic, I will try it, but I think the list may go long.

Answer (score 1):

HTML can be described in XML terms. XML has the concept of *character data*, obviously made up by *characters*. There are five characters that have special meaning in XML: `>`, `<`, `&`, `"` and `'` - these are used to define elements and delimit attributes, so the parser doesn't treat them like *normal* characters. When you need to insert a `<` literal in a XML document (like I just did in this answer), you can use a *character reference* in the form `&lt;`, so that the browser understands that you are not willing to start an XML tag. In HTML4 DTD there are [252 named entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), so it's infeasible to use `replaceAll()` to have a *readable* string.

You'd better understand how HTML works, so that you think like a web browser when you have to architect storing and rendering of your data. Note that:

```
&lt;tag&gt;
```

has **a very different meaning** than

```
<tag>
```

So you'd better argument your question to get help in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for explanation. Certainly ther are many tags available in HTML, how can I tackle with this.

Comment: @Deepu can you give a sample program, or at least state where does your input come from and where is in intended to go?

Comment: I take the data from Online XML file, which has these HTML data. I can parse XML data without any problem. This XML file changes for every minute.

Comment: And what do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I want to extract only text data from the HTML data.